# manipulating distance between two vectors

Tags: vector, distance

I am having a hard time manipulating the distance between two points.

Given x y z coordinates for A and B, and knowing their distance, how can I increase or decrease this distance keeping the angle between the 2 points?

Say point A is at 0, 0, 0 and point B is at 3, 3, 0.

I am able to calculate the distance between the two points to be 4.242.

I need to be able to "push" point B further on the same tangent by X. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Cant you multiple each coordinate of B with the same scalar?

Comment: I agree with @SajitKunnumkal, if you multiple the vector by a scalar, it's direction should be preserved.

Comment: @SajitKunnumkal that only works if point A is the origin. Otherwise a scalar multiplication of B will change the angle between A and B.

Comment: You are right.. let me think

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Subtract `A` from `B` to get the vector `D` representing the distance and direction from `A` to `B`

  ```
  D = B - A
  ```
- Multiply D by your scalar `x` to push it further from A along the same direction: (I'm changing your `X` to `x` to emphasize that it is a scalar).

  ```
  D' = xD
  ```
- Get the new point `B'` that is in the same direction from A as B is, but is further away (assuming `x > 1`):

  ```
  B' = A + D'
  ```